# Using qplot to create a density graph for three variables?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, factors, density-plot

I wish to create a density plot on `qplot()` comprising three response variables.  So the graph will be Density (y) against Elevation (x), with three colour-coded density functions showing how densities of each change as Elevation (x-axis) changes.

First I subsetted the three response variables (3 columns in my dataset "CAIRNGORM") into a small subset called "ZONES":

```
ZONES<-CAIRNGORM[c("prop_Cal", "prop_Emp", "prop_Jun")]
```

Then I tried to create the qplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Elevation, data=CAIRNGORM, geom="density", fill="ZONES", alpha=I(0.5))
```

which creates a plot but instead of giving me three traces, one for each of prop_Cal, prop_Emp and prop_Jun, I just have one trace and it appears to show the density of my Elevation data - a straight line!

I would really appreciate somebody's help with this - how do I instruct qplot to build three traces contained within "ZONES" instead of the x-variable?  Thanks

Edit: Shortened version of my data (trying to put correct code formatting in Stack Overflow):

```
> head(CAIRNGORM)
  position group Elevation 
1       Q1     A       680   
2       Q2     A       730   
3       Q3     A       780  
4       Q4     A       830     
5       Q5     A       880      
6       Q6     A       930   
  prop_bar prop_Cal prop_Vac prop_Emp prop_Jun prop_Ces prop_Eri ZONES.prop_Cal
1     0.00     1.00      0.0        0        0     0.36      0.4           1.00
2     0.00     1.00      0.0        0        0     0.28      0.0           1.00
3     0.00     0.84      0.6        0        0     0.48      0.0           0.84
4     0.00     1.00      0.0        0        0     0.00      0.0           1.00
5     0.24     0.76      0.0        0        0     0.72      0.0           0.76
6     0.36     0.72      0.0        0        0     0.00      0.0           0.72
  ZONES.prop_Emp ZONES.prop_Jun
1              0              0
2              0              0
3              0              0
4              0              0
5              0              0
6              0              0

> head(ZONES)
  prop_Cal prop_Emp prop_Jun
1     1.00        0        0
2     1.00        0        0
3     0.84        0        0
4     1.00        0        0
5     0.76        0        0
6     0.72        0        0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be most helpful if you could take some time to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), especially for a question that involves plotting.

Comment: It seems that you are working with several data frames in your question. Please provide a small sample of each in your question

Comment: Hi - thanks for editing it - I think I've worked out how to edit into code format - you put four spaces before each line?  Anyway, about my data, I'm just using just one main dataset, CAIRNGORM, and created a subset called ZONES from the three important variables within CAIRNGORM in the hope that it would allow the qplot to work, but alas it has not.  Apologies coding and R are not my forte.  I'm sure it's something simple I've done wrong.

Comment: It looks like you want a density plot of the "response variables" (meaning the columns in `ZONES`?) against `Elevation`. But a (one-dimensional) density plot is just a smoothed histogram of the distribution of values in a single variable, rather than the values of one variable relative to another. Can you say more about what you expect the plot to look like? I've posted a potential answer below, but please let me know if that's not what you had in mind and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot2` prefers data in "long" rather than "wide" format. Here's how to get the three density plots in a single graph. Because two of the columns in your sample data are all zeros, I've created some fake data for illustration:

```
library(reshape2) # For the melt function

# Fake data
ZONES = data.frame(prop_Cal=rnorm(100), 
                   prop_Emp=rnorm(100,-10,3), 
                   prop_Jun=rnorm(100,10,0.5))

# Melt into long format (take a look at the melted data frame to see what melt is doing)
ZONES.M <- melt(ZONES)

ggplot(ZONES.M, aes(value, fill=variable)) +
     geom_density(alpha=0.5)
```

`variable` contains the names of each column in your original wide-format data frame. `value` contains the values. Setting the `fill` aesthetic to `variable` tells `ggplot` to create a separate density plot for each level of `variable`.

[image]

You can't plot the density of `prop_Cal` or the other two variables against elevation. A (1-dimensional) density plot of a variable is inherently about a single variable. If you're trying to find a relationship between elevation and the other three variables, maybe you want a violin plot. For example:

```
# Fake data with Elevation added
ZONES = data.frame(Elevation=rep(c(10,20,30,40),each=25), 
                   prop_Cal=rnorm(100), 
                   prop_Emp=rnorm(100,-10,3), 
                   prop_Jun=rnorm(100,10,10))

# Melt into long format, this time with Elevation as an id variable
ZONES.M <- melt(ZONES, id.var="Elevation")

ggplot(ZONES.M, aes(Elevation, value, group=Elevation)) +
  geom_violin() +
  facet_grid(. ~ variable)
```

Now we have a density plot for each value of Elevation, separately for each of your original three column variables. (You can also combine several values of elevation first, using the `cut` function, if you want to group by elevation bands.)

[image]

If instead you want a scatterplot of each variable vs. Elevation, you can do this:

```
ggplot(ZONES.M, aes(Elevation, value, group=Elevation)) +
  geom_point(colour="black", fill="lightblue", alpha=0.5, pch=21) +
  facet_grid(. ~ variable)
```

If you want to add a regression line (which may be what you're actually looking for if you want to summarise the relationship between Elevation and the other three variables), do this:

```
ggplot(ZONES.M, aes(Elevation, value, group=Elevation)) +
  geom_point(colour="black", fill="lightblue", alpha=0.5, pch=21) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group=1)) +  
  facet_grid(. ~ variable)
```

Comment: Wow - thanks!  However, I wish to plot Elevation along the x-axis.  I tried replacing "value" with "dataset$Elevation" and it did not work.  My variable data values correspond to a particular Elevation value and I'd like to represent the densities of each variable at changing Elevation.  I don't know if this is possible to do.